# How to handle another Excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, iterable, nonetype

Good Morning.
I'm starting with Python and I have a problem.
I need to find all .xls files (all have the same header) and merge all into a single DataFrame, so I need to say that the first line of the file should be ignored.
The current code I'm using is this:

```
os.chdir("file folder path")
fileLista = glob.glob('*.xls')
df = list()
for arquivo in fileLista:
    df = df.append(pd.read_excel(arquivo))
    Company= pd.concat(df)
    Company.columns = Company.columns.str.strip()
```

I am using Glob to return all the .xls extension files,
df.append is to merge all the files that have been returned and put inside a DataFrame,
Company concat is to form a single file,
Company strip is to remove the spaces that it has in the column header.
When I run the code it returns me this error:
**"erro NoneType' object is not iterable"**

Can anyone help me with this mistake?

Comment: which line triggers the error?

Comment: can you share the full traceback?

Comment: have you checked the output of `glob.glob('*.xls')`. this is probably, where your error is coming from. also no need of `df.append`, you are already iterating over `fileLista`, just `pd.concat`, should be enough.

Comment: objs = list (objs) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Line error 'Company = pd.concat(df)'

Comment: Sim, verifiquei a saída do glob.glob e ele está me retornando os arquivos certos. Então devo retirar o df.append ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this instead?

```
fileLista = glob.glob('*.xls')
Company = pd.DataFrame()
for arquivo in fileLista:
    df = pd.read_excel(arquivo)
    Company= pd.concat([Company,df])
    Company.columns = Company.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me how I can indicate the excel tab to be read and how to ignore the first lines? I learned how to do this pd.read_excel ('filename.xls', sheet_name = 'tabname', skiprows = 1). I do this when it's just a file, in which case how can I keep it that way?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  You can query Excel files with: `xlfile = pd.ExcelFile(arquivo)`, `names = xlfile.sheet_names`.  (Also, if the posted answer above is acceptable, please click to accept the answer.)

Comment: Thank you so much, the answer has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import glob
glob.glob("C:/your_path_here/*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:/your_path_here/*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    print(all_data)
```

Here is another option to consider.

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["C:/your_path_here/Book1.xlsx", "C:/your_path_here/Book2.xlsx", "C:/your_path_here/Book3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)


# Results go to the default directory if not assigned somewhere else.
# C:\Users\Excel\.spyder-py3
```